# Incorrect row ID returned in simple select query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using Codeigntier to run the a query like this:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT users.*, user_profiles.* FROM users, user_profiles WHERE " . "users.id = $user_id AND user_profiles.user_id = $user_id");
$row = $query->row();
```

I have placed an echo to get the last query `$this->db->last_query()`. Which shows:

```
SELECT users.*, user_profiles.* FROM users, user_profiles WHERE users.id = 6850 AND user_profiles.user_id = 6850
```

The result it returns is:

```
object(stdClass)[24]
  public 'id' => string '6849' (length=4)
```

The id the result shows is `6849`. I nearly fell of my chair! I ran the same query on my MySQL database and the id returned for that exact same query is `6850`. 6850 is the correct ID.

I have no idea how to debug this as this is the simplest of queries. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Instead of using `$user_id` for both tables, try joining them.  Maybe that's what's messing it up?  `"WHERE users.id = $user_id AND user_profiles.user_id = users.id"`

Comment: Rocket beat me to the punch (+1) -- `$sql = '
 SELECT 
  users.*, 
  user_profiles.* 
 FROM 
  users, 
  user_profiles 
 WHERE 
  users.id = '.$user_id.' AND 
  user_profiles.user_id = users.id 
';` That probably isn't 100% of the problem, but that is a more standard way to join tables and it can't hurt.

Comment: Also, `SELECT *...` is usually bad practice :) Rather, you should name your columns explicitly. It makes debugging simpler should the table structure change unexpectedly (like a different developer).

Comment: OK, I tried Rocket's idea and got the same result. I also tried a simpler join `SELECT * FROM users JOIN user_profiles ON users.id = user_profiles.user_id AND users.id = $user_id`. Still getting the same issue!

Comment: @Abs I didn't think that was **the** problem, but it is better practice anyway. Now, instead of passing your query straight to `$this->db->query`, put it in a variable and `die($sql);` BEFORE you execute the query. I strongly suspect that you're getting lied to by `$this->db->last_query()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Explicitly select your columns, and `AS *something*` alias them. Then check the ID's.

It is likely that the id of the table `user_profiles` is being shown rather than the actual user id from the `users` table that you expect as you are not specifying the columns.

Comment: BINGO! This is correct and I understand why! Thank you. I can stop laughing now and get back to other problems that I should be solving!

Comment: @Abs the value `6849` is from the `user_profiles` tables because the id column overrides the id column of users tables Rob is right you have to alias the columns

Comment: @dianuj You are right, I just edited this answer to explain that. This is what happens when you don't follow best practice of specifying the columns you want.

Comment: Feel free to mark as the correct answer so others are aware :)

Comment: I'm happy to mark this as the answer. I left it for a bit hoping you could get more up-votes as this answer has saved me some time.